# How to use firestore emulator from client

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I want to test locally my firebase functions.
These functions make firestore queries.

So i start the emulator `firebase emulators:start` and in my client i use `firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001')`.

My functions work well when i call them in my client. I can read/write data inside the firestore emulator.

The problem :

I want to read the firestore emulator data directly inside my client, like :

```
firebase.firestore().collection('tests').get().then(tests => {
    console.log( tests.docs.map(test=>test.map) )
})
```

but i can't find how to set the firestore emulator inside my client.

here what i tried:

1) Firestore setting

```
firebase.firestore().settings({
    host:'http://localhost:8080',
    ssl:false
})
```

result :

i get `@firebase/firestore: Firestore (6.3.5): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.` inside my client console.

The http request returns 'Not found'

2) Set the emulator url inside my firebaseConfig

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    // ...
    databaseURL: "http://localhost:8080",
    // ...
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

in this case, the remote server (https://firestore.googleapis.com..) is requested.

So i want to setup one of these two cases :

1) Using the remote firestore inside my functions emulators

OR

2) Using the local firestore emulator inside my client code.

Anyone has already done this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i found how to do it :

1) launch the functions emulator locally:

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./privatekey.json && firebase serve --only functions
```

2) then client side:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001')
}
```

Comment: Then what about the Firestore Emulator and the test data? You go straight to the production server for the database?

Answer (score 11):

#### Install the testing lib

```
npm i -D @firebase/testing
```

#### Setup and start the emulator in another terminal:

```
firebase setup:emulators:firestore

firebase serve --only firestore
```

#### Setup the tests

```
const firebase = require("@firebase/testing");

// Helper function to setup test db
function authedApp(auth) {
  return firebase
    .initializeTestApp({ projectId: FIRESTORE_PROJECT_ID, auth })
    .firestore();
}

// Setup methods
beforeEach(async () => {
  // Clear the database between tests
  await firebase.clearFirestoreData({ projectId: FIRESTORE_PROJECT_ID });
});

// Clean up apps between tests.
afterEach(async () => {
  await Promise.all(firebase.apps().map(app => app.delete()));
});
```

#### Run the tests

```
it("should retrieve correct item", async () => {
  // Init test db
  const db = authedApp(null);

  // Manually add item to collection
  const ref = await db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).add({name: 'test item'});

  // Fetch item by id 
  const resp = await db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).doc(ref.id).get();

  // test the output
  expect(resp).toBeDefined();
  expect(resp).toEqual(expect.objectContaining({name: 'test item'}));
});
```

Of course your particular setup and circumstances will differ, but this at least should give you a general idea. More info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests

Note from '[Test your Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator)'

> Data written to the Cloud Firestore emulator is held in memory until
>   the emulator is stopped. If the emulator is run continuously, this may
>   have an impact on test isolation. To ensure that data written in one
>   test is not read in another, either explicitly clear your data with
>   `clearFirestoreData`, or assign a different project ID for each
>   independent test: when you call firebase.initializeAdminApp or
>   firebase.initializeTestApp, append a user ID, timestamp, or random
>   integer to the projectID.

**Edit:** I wrote a [blog post](https://claritydev.net/blog/testing-firestore-locally-with-firebase-emulators/) a while back, which goes into more detail about the subject.

Comment: Will there be real data written in the firestore db using this method?

Comment: Never mind, found the answer in the docs and I've added it to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem too. I found the following example, which looks like its still work in progress:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/tree/master/firestore-emulator/browser-quickstart

They didn't use `@firebase/testing` directly in their example. When I did try to embed `@firebase/testing` in my webpack code, it tries to connect via `grpc`, which attempts to do `fs.existsSync`, which doesn't exist in `webpack` browser context. They prefer to enable the functionality via [WebChannel](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.net.WebChannel.html) instead.

<s>Some caveats as of Nov 2019:</s>

- <s>You might see errors in the console connecting to localhost:8080 with the X-Goog-API. I am not sure what is that for.</s>
- <s>You might get the following error: `@firebase/firestore: Firestore (6.3.5): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.`</s>

<s>Despite having those errors, my functions were still able to connect to the local firestore.</s>

<s>Versions I had at time I was testing:</s>

- firebase-js-sdk 6.3.1
- firebase-tools 7.3.1

Update 11/18:

- I raised an issue within `quickstart-nodejs` github and it seems I just needed to use the latest versions of everything.

Versions:

- firebase-js-sdk v7.4.0
- firebase-tools v7.8.0

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this is trivial... In your firestore cient config you should have provided the **host**, not the origin for firestore (the protocol is set using the `ssl` parameter):

```
firebase.firestore().settings({
    host: 'localhost:8080',
    ssl: false
})
```

At least this solved it for me when I had the exact same error.

Just FYI to anyone who's reading this - if you run into problems with the firestore client, you can use `debug` level logging, just set `firebase.firestore.setLogLevel('debug')`. Had the OP done that, he might have noticed that firebase is accessing firestore at `http://http://localhost:8080/`...

Comment: This is it with `firebase-admin ^9.2.0` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Define the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable**

If you are using a library that supports the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable, run:

> export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080

or just add *FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080* to your .env file