# Why don't I see data in the Firebase Cloud Firestore Emulator UI?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I have some tests for security rules and they prime up a dataset to the local Firestore emulator (using the `@firebase/testing` library, pretty much as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57537017/how-to-use-firestore-emulator-from-client)). The tests mostly work, so I think the data really gets to Firestore.

But I cannot see it in the emulator UI.

http://localhost:4000/ > Firestore emulator > Go to emulator shows empty data

Related, I wonder what is the role of the ”project ID” parameter in emulation?  It is required when setting up the Firebase app object, but where is it used?  The emulator does not provide me a list of emulated projects, to pick from.

Confused.

---

Ways to replicate (as requested):

```
$ git clone git@github.com:akauppi/GroundLevel-es6-firebase-web.git
$ cd GroundLevel-es6-firebase-web/rules-test

# You only need to work in the rules-test subproject

$ npm install
...
```

In another terminal (same folder):

```
$ npm run start    # leave running...
```

```
$ npm run test:symbols
```

The tests should pass (one is skipped).

The running of the tests has primed data to the emulator, and it should still be there. Project id `abc` (see "Using session:  abc" on the output).

http://localhost:4000/ > Go to emulator

**Expected:**

- being able to select project `abc`
- being able to see the primed data (btw. it's in `data.js`)

**Actual:**

- there is no project id selection
- there is no data

[image: screenshot of Firestore emulator]

I know too little to know, what's going on. Maybe `@firebase/testing` never reaches the emulator, and I should be using the normal Firebase client, instead?

Comment: Found a discussion that tangents this one - especially the project ID. It seems they are fake when @firebase/testing is used. Is this so? https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1960

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code and procedure you're using that isn't working the way you expect.  There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce what you see.

Comment: @DougStevenson Fair, added

Comment: Adding because this came up in my search for "firestore emulator not showing root nodes"; **check that you are running the latest emulator updates**. In my case I had sub-collections with empty parent documents, which were [not getting displayed in the UI](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools-ui/issues/273) of my few-months-old emulator installation.

Answer (score 18):

The emulator UI only shows the active project, i.e. the one used in `firebase use`.

If tests use this project ID, their data is visible in the emulator. If they use some other, tests work but the emulator UI is out of the loop.

Not sure if this is by design or not. If you know a place in the documentation that addresses this, I'll be glad to mention it here.

`firebase-tools` 8.6.0

Comment: This was my issue. This is not in the documentation anywhere.

Comment: It is working! Thanks! You save me a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

I was using a fake project id for the emulator as same as the API key. I had to use my `projectId` to solve the issue. Thanks to this [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2365#issuecomment-644051826).

> when calling `admin.initializeApp()` you need to set the correct
> `projectId`, then the data will show up.

Comment: Is there any way to make the emulator show data for a fake project id?

Answer (score 1):

Today I bumped into this too.

For me the issue is that I had accidentally removed the `.firebaserc` file (which was gitignored) from the project.

As a result, the emulator UI would not show any Firestore documents at all.

Adding back the project with `firebase use --add` solved the problem.

But I wasted a bunch of time on this. One would hope that the emulator should throw a fatal error if any required configuration files are missing.