# Use Firebase-functions-emulator with remote firebase services

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

Can I connect the firebase-functions-emulator with the remote authentication and firestore service? Currently it is connecting only to the other local emulators. I don't want to setup my db locally.

Comment: Hi quinzo, was the information provided in the answer below useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have the local Cloud Functions emulator respond to (or "trigger" on) events in a production database. You have to deploy your functions in order for them to execute in response to change in the cloud-hosted database. The local functions emulator only responds to changes in the locally emulated database.
Refer the following to understand how to [Connect your app to the Realtime Database Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions)

Check a [similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57537017/how-to-use-firestore-emulator-from-client) here.